# Text Gradient Chrome Only Issue

Tags: css

CSS

```
    h1 {
      font-size: 72px;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    }
```

HTML

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

I see the 'Hello World' text with the gradient in chrome browser. Even though I add other prefixers such as -moz,-mo I don't see it in firefox or opera or IE. What could be the issue?

Comment: [This is for Webkit only](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/gradient-text/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think only WebKit-based browsers implement the text-fill-color property. As far as I'm aware, there is no workaround for Mozilla yet.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
    background: $gradient;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    display: inline-block;
```

Working on all browsers for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the same for -moz and -o(simone comment)

here you can find an example for linear-gradients.
http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/linear-gradients/#.UNQ9Ztd2EuM

**EDIT**
unfortunatly the previous poster is right
[-moz-background-clip:text does not work in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362639/moz-background-cliptext-does-not-work-in-firefox)

Comment: What I want is text gradient.

Answer (score 0):

check [this](http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). It is an awesome site for the gradient. You can make any gradient for any browser at a same time and it also supports old version of ie.

Comment: these are not text gradients

Comment: But the gradient for text is only supported by Webkit - based browser. Sorry

Comment: to make your text fill with gradient u must edit with softwares like photoshop.Because other browser don't support text gradient.

Comment: http://vectips.com/tutorials/quick-tutorial-adding-gradients-to-text/ this will be helpful for you