# Background-image under text not working in Mozilla

Tags: css, browser-support

I have this: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/87xgmner/2/)

```
background-image: url('http://colorisrelative.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/halation_2color_orangecyan.png');
background-position: 80% 0%;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

I put a background-image under the icons and change the position on hover.
It works perfectly in Chrome, but not in Mozilla or IE (You need to watch the demo in chrome and Moz or IE).
So I need a fallback. I tried the solution of [this article](https://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/) but I dont get it to work.

Is there a way to say, use it only in chrome and take a static text color with hover in every other browser?

I appreciate every solution

Comment: Where is the text that you are referring to? the icons? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, the icons, sorry. I revised it.

Comment: I think same effect can be reached with just text color and opacity for two icon states. But if you will have complex text background - https://github.com/myadzel/patternizer can help for mozilla.

Comment: What i wanted to achieve is the animation of the background image sliding to the right on hover. Thanks! Ill try it.

Comment: Take a look at this post: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362639/moz-background-cliptext-does-not-work-in-firefox

Comment: So there is no solution? Is there no way to check if its chrome and give him a class with the background-image else give him another class with a static color?