# How can I insert image in the text instead of a color using CSS3?

Tags: html, css

I have a text heading which is white in color. I want to put an image instead of white color to the text. The Text is big enough to show the image which will be filled in.

[image]

This is what I basically want..
There's completely different background image behind the text and I want to fill in another image on the text.

Comment: "because of less repo" -- huh?

Comment: So you want that text to be kinda mask for a pic? Now, that would be a sight!

Comment: You might want to look at the [CSS background -clip property](http://nimbupani.com/using-background-clip-for-text-with-css-fallback.html).

Comment: I would do that in Photoshop, creating a png with a transparent background and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `background-clip` to mask up the text. Here's the solution:

```
<h1>Shashank Jaiswal</h1>
h1 {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 5em;
    text-align: center;

    background-image: url(http://tn.clashot.com/thumbs/3391302/58941884/thumb_w800.jpg);

    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;

    color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/gnoyubwc/

Comment: Thanks. It's working for chrome.
I tried -moz-background-clip:text; but didn't work in Firefox...
I have got some ideas... trying now.

Comment: refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362639/moz-background-cliptext-does-not-work-in-firefox - sorry about that :(

Answer (score -1):

You can use photoshop for that and create a clipping mask. You'll get exactly what you wanted!