# CSS3 gradient not working in firefox and IE (works in chrome)

Tags: css, gradient

I created a gradient class for text. It works nicely in google chrome but in firefox and internet explorer it doesn't. In these browsers there is an actual background gradient visible behind the text which I don't want.

I created a fiddle where this browser-different behavior can be perceived.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lzhvsowq/

```
<h1 class="gradient_blue" style="font-size: 60px;">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</h1>

.gradient_blue {
  color: #288cc7;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #288cc7;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #288cc7 0%, #206e9b 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #288cc7 0%, #206e9b 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #288cc7 0%, #206e9b 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#288cc7', endColorstr='#206e9b', GradientType=1);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: transparent?? https://jsfiddle.net/Lzhvsowq/5/

Comment: Should i post it as answer?

Comment: @rails_has-elegance sorry but i have removed my answer as transparent means no use of gradient. You won't get gradient in chrome after use transparent and it will lead to wrong way to new user so sorry.

Comment: oh i completely misinterpreted your answer. it actually does not work, you're right. you removed the gradients alltogether. any other solution possible?

Comment: as far as i know..sorry.. but hope you will get some one :)

Comment: The effect in question comes from the `background-clip` property and its value `text`. As mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9371581/2851870), the `text` property is not a standard CSS property and is a proprietary WebKit feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using WebKit only features, such as `-webkit-background-clip: text`, and this is why it is going to work only on Chrome, Safari and Opera. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like there is a similar feature for IE or Firefox.

Probably the best alternative for non-WebKit browsers if you want to make a text gradient is to use [SVG gradients](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_grad_linear.asp) (jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8y3fajxj/)):

```
<h1 class="gradient_blue" style="font-size: 60px;">
<svg height="100%" width="100%">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" x2="100%" y1="0%" y2="0%">
          <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#288cc7;" />
          <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#206e9b;" />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <text fill="url(#gradient)" x="1%" y="30%">
         Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
      </text>
 </svg>
 </h1>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Both answers are perfect. Gave the bounty for this one because of the nice svg solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are using two webkit extension properties:

```css
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

Sadly it's too late to kill them, so [Compatibility](https://compat.spec.whatwg.org/) spec has standardized them.

Now non-webkit browsers are implementing them, but they are not yet supported in stable channels.

In the case of Firefox, it works in latest Nightly. Relevant bugs are:

- [Bug 1247777](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1247777) - Implement the -webkit-text-fill-color property
- [Bug 1263516](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1263516) - Enable background-clip:text preference in non-release builds
- [Bug 759568](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=759568) - Implement -webkit-background-clip: text (as background-clip: text)

So just wait. Or better, don't use these properties which should never have existed.

Comment: why should they never have existed?

Comment: @rails_has_elegance See for example https://www.chromium.org/blink#vendor-prefixes. Browsers have realized properties with vendor prefixes are horrible, but it's too late.